# using Band sdk on portable class library

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library, microsoft-band

I'm developing a portable class library that targets Universal Windows and .Net Applications, I installed Microsoft.Band SDK from NuGet, this resolved most of the band symbols:

```
IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
```

IBandInfo is accepted, but BandClientManager raises an error:

```
The Name BandClientManager does not exist in the current context
```

Both Symbols are from the SDK, any reason one is defined, while the other is not resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BandClientManager` type is specific to the platform on which the Band SDK is being used (e.g. Windows Phone or Windows Store), due (in part) to differences in the Bluetooth API between platforms.  It's not portable so it cannot be used directly from a Portable Class Library that targets multiple platforms.

Instead, you need to limit your use of the Band SDK in your PCL to the `IBandClientManager` interface, which *is* portable.  Then, your platform-specific library can inject the appropriate `BandClientManager.Instance` at runtime.

Comment: Where do we get the platform specific versions of the library? Can an `IBandClientManager` be instantiated for example on Linux?